# cf.net app protection (antidebug, obfuscate)

Tags: .net, compact-framework, obfuscation, copy-protection

Is there any out-of-the box solution that protects cf.net (3.5) software against reverse engineering and unlicensed redistribution (*average* hacker protection)? Any option of packer/native wrapper?

Answer (score 3):

We use [Xenocode Postbuild](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild-for-NET/) for everything we need to obfuscate.  Be aware that just about any obfuscation of your assembly will slow its execution.

**EDIT**

PostBuild is no longer available, and in fact their license server went offline, so even if you had a licensed version, you can no longer use it (why couldn't you just release the source, people?).  We've moved to [LogicNP's Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) which was fairly intuitive and still works just fine with Compact Framework assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator.html

Answer (score 1):

I use [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) - it's free and it's good.

Answer (score 1):

All the above solutions will work for you but if you want something cost effective, you can try http://www.eziriz.com/ - .NET reactor. I have used the trial version and it is as effective as preemptive and remotesoft salamander but for a much lower cost - it is only $179 for a single developer license and $279 for a company license - more details here - http://www.eziriz.com/order.htm

Answer (score 0):

[Remotesoft Salamander .NET Obfuscator](http://www.remotesoft.com/salamander/obfuscator.html)

Answer (score 0):

[Smart Assembly](http://www.smartassembly.com/product/index.aspx)